# com.sun.net.HttpServer + SheduledExecutorService + sheduleWithFixedDelay - command runnable

Tags: java

I am working with `sheduler.sheduleWithFixedDelay(????, 5,3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`. What runnable command should I place here?
It is webserver that sends "hello" response. I want add delay to server answer.

I have modified my code, thank you to **matt**. Now I have runnable command but have no delay..

```
void main(...){
 SheduledExecutorService sheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
 HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8001),5);
 server.createContext("/test", (exchange -> {
    String respText = "";
    String requestText = CFG.getConntent(exchange);
    if (requestText.contains("Hello")){
        respText = "Hello";
    }
    else if (requestText.contains("Bye")){
        respText = "Bye";
    }
    
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
    String textToSend = respText;   
    sheduler.sheduleWithFixedDelay(()->{
        OutputStream output = exchange.getResponseBody();
        try{            
            output.write(textToSend.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            output.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}        
        exchange.close();
    }, 0,10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

 
 server.setExecutor(sheduler);
 server.start();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be delayed?

Comment: answer from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you need to put the delay in your response.

```
server.createContext("/test", (exchange -> {
    String respText = "hello";
    String requestText = CFG.getConntent(exchange);
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);

    sheduler.sheduleWithFixedDelay(()->{
        OutputStream output = exchange.getResponseBody();
        output.write(resp.Text.getBytes(UTF_8));
        output.flush();
        exchange.close();
    }, 5,3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

});
```

This should cause the responds body to finish sending after the delay. I figured it should start the response by sending the '200' ok signal first.

Comment: for me says respText - variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final...

Comment: though i changed to:
String textToSend = respText;
...
output.write(textToSend .getBytes(UTF_8));
And no errors. a bit more time to test. Sorry.

Comment: there is no errors, but there is no pauses.. the answer i got right that moment i send request in browser...

Comment: though i have changed to 10,10 in timeOut and it works fine